how to make the xAxis dynamic using HighCharts
How make the x-axis dynamic for handling date-time data and zooming. I wanted the x-axis to dynamically display the year, then month and year, and finally date and time based on the zoom level (zoomType: 'x'). Here's the complete implementation:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Highcharts Dynamic xAxis</title>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
    <script>
var xAxisData = [
            "07/12/2016 12:00:00 am",
            "07/12/2016 01:00:00 am",
            "07/12/2016 02:00:00 am",
            "07/12/2016 03:00:00 am",
            "07/12/2016 04:00:00 am",
            "07/12/2016 12:00:00 pm",
            "07/12/2016 01:00:00 pm",
            "07/12/2016 02:00:00 pm",
            "07/12/2016 03:00:00 pm",
            "07/12/2016 11:00:00 pm",
            "08/12/2016 05:00:00 am",
            "08/12/2016 06:00:00 am",
            "08/12/2016 07:00:00 am",
            "08/12/2016 09:00:00 am",
            "08/12/2016 10:00:00 am",
            "08/12/2016 10:00:00 am",
            "08/12/2016 12:00:00 pm",
            "08/12/2016 03:34:29 pm",
            "08/12/2016 04:00:00 pm",
            "08/12/2016 05:00:00 pm",
            "08/12/2016 06:34:29 pm",
            "08/12/2016 07:34:29 pm",
            "08/12/2016 08:34:29 pm",
            "08/12/2016 10:00:00 pm",
            "08/12/2016 11:00:00 pm",
            "09/12/2016 12:00:00 am",
            "09/12/2016 01:00:00 am",
            "09/12/2016 02:00:00 am",
            "09/12/2016 03:00:00 am",
            "09/12/2016 04:00:00 am",
            "09/12/2016 12:00:00 pm",
            "09/12/2016 01:00:00 pm",
            "09/12/2016 02:00:00 pm",
            "09/12/2016 03:00:00 pm",
            "09/12/2016 11:00:00 pm",
            "10/12/2016 12:00:00 am",
            "10/12/2016 01:00:00 am",
            "10/12/2016 02:00:00 am",
            "10/12/2016 03:00:00 am",
            "10/12/2016 04:00:00 am",
            "10/12/2016 12:00:00 pm",
            "10/12/2016 01:00:00 pm",
            "10/12/2016 02:00:00 pm",
            "10/12/2016 03:00:00 pm",
            "10/12/2016 11:00:00 pm"
        ];

        var tabY= [
            39966.31,
            38054.98,
            43569.27,
            43619.26,
            43735.39,
            43619.26,
            39895.25,
            39966.31,
            43201.27,
            40043.66,
            40071.34,
            38794.64,
            39480.24,
            40869.52,
            43735.39,
            43582.69,
            43735.39,
            43692.54,
            60093.51,
            43201.27,
            40093.51,
            42580.97,
            43619.26,
            38556.31,
            40043.66,
            39000.49,
            39966.31,
            43201.27,
            38865.23,
            42093.24,
            40071.34,
            43637.56,
            38996.11,
            40071.34,
            42093.24,
            40014.85,
            43576.01,
            40093.51,
            43201.27,
            38865.23,
            39966.31,
            38794.64,
            39895.25,
            40093.51,
            40043.66
        ];
Highcharts.chart('container', {
                        exporting: {
                            buttons: {
                                contextButton: {
                                    menuItems: ["downloadPNG", "downloadPDF"]
                                }
                            },
                            sourceWidth: 1502,
                            scale: 1,
                            chartOptions: {
                                chart: {
                                    height: this.chartHeight
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        chart: {
                            zoomType: 'x',
                            type: 'column'
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Relevé de prélèvement des températures et de la Salinité',
                            align: 'left'
                        },
                        subtitle: {
                            text: "Site : " + data.nom + " du " + data.DisplayStartDate + " au " + data.DisplayEndDate + " (inclus)",
                            align: 'left'
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            type: 'datetime',
                            title: {
                                text: "Date (Heure, GMT +03:00)"
                            },
                            categories: xAxisData
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            min: 0,
                            title: {
                                text: selectedValues[0] === "1" ? "Conductivite" : "Temperature",
                                style: { color: "#B5C0D0" }
                            }
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            valueSuffix: selectedValues[0] === "1" ? " µS/cm" : " °C",
                            xDateFormat: '%e %b %Y, %H:%M'
                        },
                        legend: {
                            layout: 'vertical',
                            align: 'left',
                            x: 80,
                            verticalAlign: 'top',
                            y: 55,
                            floating: true,
                            backgroundColor: Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || 'rgba(255,255,255,0.25)'
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            column: {
                                pointPadding: 0.2,
                                borderWidth: 0
                            }
                        },
                        series: [{
                            name: 'Conductivite',
                            data: tabY
                        }]
                    });
</script>
</body>
</html>

Output :
enter image description here
Wanted my x-axis to behave as much as follows :
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/highcharts/line-boost
Please help.

To make the x-axis behave as in the example you sent, you cannot use categories, but provide the x and y values ​​as series.data in the format:
series: [{
  data: [{
    x: 1481065200000,
    y: 39966.31
  }, {
    x: 1481068800000,
    y: 38054.98
  }, ...]
}]

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k7ubpj8e/ 
API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data
